# button does not enter the switch case

Tags: c, winapi

basically what I'm trying to do is to visualize my text box and buttons in the first window(`HWinRicerca = CreateWindowW(L"static",...`) and for that I thought I could give it a handler and then the other textbox and buttons would be internally in the window by just passing the handler of the first(HWinRicerca) instead the one of the main(hWnd). everything is fine, the problems comes with the button, which if it's in HWinRicerca it doesnt enter in WM_COMMAND in the CERCA_UT_RI case but if it is in hWnd works fine.
What's the reason?

```
void AddControls(HWND hWnd)
{
    HWinRicerca = CreateWindowW(L"static",L"Ricerca Utente",WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER | SS_CENTER|WS_THICKFRAME,350,40,250,135,hWnd,NULL,NULL,NULL);
    CreateWindowW(L"static",L"Nome :",WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER | SS_CENTER,30,35,50,20,HWinRicerca,NULL,NULL,NULL);
    HricercaMain = CreateWindowW(L"edit", NULL,  WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER |ES_MULTILINE | ES_AUTOVSCROLL,80,35,130,20,HWinRicerca,NULL,NULL,NULL);
    CreateWindowW(L"Button",L"Conferma",WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD ,80,70,70,40,HWinRicerca,(HMENU)CERCA_UT_RI,NULL,NULL);
}
```

here's the window procedure:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure(HWND hWnd,UINT msg,WPARAM wp,LPARAM lp){
    switch(msg){
        case WM_COMMAND:
            switch(wp){
                case UTENTE_NUOVO:
                    MessageBeep(MB_RIGHT);
                    displayAggUT(hWnd);
                    break;
                case RISTORANTE_NUOVO:
                    MessageBeep(MB_RIGHT);
                    displayAggRI(hWnd);
                    break;
                case UTENTE_MODIFICA:
                   MessageBeep(MB_RIGHT);
                   displayModUT(hWnd);
                   break;
                case RISTORANTE_MODIFICA:
                   MessageBeep(MB_RIGHT);
                   displayModRI(hWnd);
                   break;
                case UTENTE_CANCELLA:
                    MessageBeep(MB_RIGHT);
                    displayDelUT(hWnd);
                    break;
                case RISTORANTE_CANCELLA:
                    MessageBeep(MB_RIGHT);
                    displayDelRI(hWnd);
                    break;
                case CERCA_UT_RI:
                {
                    printf("hello\n");
                    utente *ut;
                    MessageBeep(MB_RIGHT);
                    ut = Cerca_utM(HricercaMain);
                } 
                break;
                case HELP:
                        MessageBox(NULL,"..."," Come Funziona?", MB_ICONQUESTION);
                        break;
            }
        break;
    case WM_CREATE:
        IMPORT();
        AddMenus(hWnd);
        AddControls(hWnd);
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
                PostQuitMessage(0);
                break;
        default:
             return DefWindowProcW(hWnd,msg,wp,lp);
    }
}
```

Comment: A button sends `WM_COMMAND` to its parent. You're creating the button as a child of a static control, so the `WM_COMMAND` message will be going to that static control, which ignores it. If you want to receive that message you need to sub-class the static control.

Comment: Either that, or follow the more conventional approach, and make the controls that (visually) live inside a static control siblings of that static control.